# Issue auto-refreshing background image with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using a live stream of a webcam for the background image of my personal website and I am having a problem with it auto refreshing every 2seconds.

Site: [daviddiliberto.com](http://www.daviddiliberto.com)

Feed source:

```
http://207.251.86.238/cctv7.jpg
```

My CSS needs to override a theme that carries out over the rest of the site. So I injected it with this here:

```
#main {
background-image: url("http://207.251.86.238/cctv7.jpg");
background-size: cover;
}
```

My JavaScript:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

function reloadBackground() {
url = "http://207.251.86.238/cctv7.jpg?" + new Date().getTime();
img = document.getElementByClassId("#main");
img.src = url;
}

</script>
```

And in my HTML:

```
<body onLoad="setInterval('reloadBackground()',2000)">
```

I am not good with JavaScript so really thanks for any help!!!

Comment: Two things:  assuming you're using the Date/Time as a cache-buster, you should be putting a "?" after the "...cctv7.jpg" string, and ".full-width-homepage.collection-type-page.homepage" isn't an id; it's a class (several, in fact).

Comment: Looking at your website source, you have your <body> tag in the middle of other HTML.  The BODY tag should be an immediate child of <HTML>, and there should only be one of them.

Comment: ok thanks! I have updated the above code to reflect what is on the site now. Unfortunatly im not sure where I can inject the BODY tag in my code. I am using Squarespace as a CMS and kinda hard to figure out where to place it properly... ;-/

Answer (score 0):

There is no element with this Id.

What you should be doing is to `getElementByClassName`. However, I'm not sure that you can concatenate classes names using that function.

```
//don't use dots '.' or hashes in the parameter
document.getElementByClassName("full-width-homepage");
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many things wrong with the way you're trying to do this.  There's no document.getElementByClassId() method; "#main" isn't an image, so there's no .src property on it; you don't need to put the onLoad() in a BODY tag; you can't have two BODY tags; you can't have a BODY tag embedded in a document like that....  and so on.

This should work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById("main").style.backgroundImage = "url("
            + "http://207.251.86.238/cctv7.jpg?"
            + new Date().getTime()
            + ")";
    }, 2000);
</script>
```